# `display: none` vs conditional render in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm having trouble deciding the difference between these two patterns of rendering in React. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this matter.

**Pattern 1: React's Conditional Render**

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

```js
class List extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menu: false,
  }
  handleMouseOver = () => {
    this.setState({
      menu: true
    });
  }
  handleMouseLeave = () => {
    this.setState({
      menu: false
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { menu } = this.state;

    return (
      <li
        onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver}
        onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
      >
        {menu && <Menu />}
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

**Pattern 2:** `display: none`

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}

.li:hover .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
const List = () => (
  <li className="li"><Menu className="menu"/></li>
);
```

**Question:**

If I need to render 100 of these items in a single page, which pattern should I go for?

How can I determine which pattern is better?

Are there any performance benefit of using one over the other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tend to use `display: none` in situations where there's a simple condition to show something (e.g hover, etc).
If it's a bit more complex (e.g. click a checkbox to hide an element) then I go with conditional rendering.
The reason behind this is that I don't want to cause state changes and trigger an update for something as trivial as a hover state, and don't want to fiddle around with obscure css classes for things that will have to involve code anyway.

Again, this is my personal preference.

*TL;DR*: CSS if super simple (e.g. hover), conditional​ render if more logic involved

Comment: Also when are you listening to DOM events imperatively on the elements that is eventually going to be removed from DOM tree by React (conditional rendering case), things might be a little spooky. CSS `hidden` is better in that case.